# Can I make the 'new' keyword optional with classes in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In JavaScript, there's a little trick you can use to make the `new` keyword optional:

```
function Frob(args) {
  if (!(this instanceof Frob)) {
    return new Frob(args);
  }

  // Normal initialization logic
}
```

This way, you can instantiate a `Frob` with or without the `new` keyword:

```
new Frob('foo'); // a Frob instance
Frob('bar');     // also a Frob instance
```

Is there a way to do this with the `class` keyword in CoffeeScript?

Comment: I find that you've decreased readability here by taking away "new". What's the upside?

Comment: @jcollum: As I'm sure you'll agree, readability is a very subjective thing. The upside is simply the option of exposing a certain flavor of API, if that is your preference. I might argue that if my library provides a consistent interface and good documentation, making `new` optional *improves* readability (for some) by making the code more concise. But I don't think it's black and white.

Comment: I suppose it'd be plenty readable if the name implied creation: `FrobFactory('bar')`. I agree that it's subjective but bypassing a feature of the language doesn't seem helpful to someone who's never seen your code before.

Comment: @jcollum: It depends on so many things. If you looked at jQuery for the first time you might say, "This is a horrible API because it is not intuitive at all what `$` is supposed to do." But then, with some time investment on the developer's part in learning the personality of the library, the conciseness of the API becomes a joy (again, for some). I was just asking if it's possible.  I am sure there are cases where using this approach would be a mistake. Maybe even most cases. That doesn't mean it would *always* be a mistake.

Comment: In my experience I would say that readability has a lot to do with what _most_ people are used to and what they expect when they read code. I assume that most people are used to use build-in keywords and expect to see them. If I see a function without a _new_, I would not expect that this is a constructor. I also think it is redundant to use a name that implies creation instead of the _new_ keyword that also implies creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define a constructor:

```
class Frob
  constructor: (args) ->
    return new Frob(args) unless this instanceof Frob
    ### Rest of your init code ###
```

[Output](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Frob%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28args%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Frob%28args%29%20unless%20this%20instanceof%20Frob%0A):

```
var Frob;

Frob = (function() {
  function Frob(args) {
    if (!(this instanceof Frob)) {
      return new Frob(args);
    }
  }

  return Frob;

})();
```